# Spring Validation Framework without Annotations

Tags: spring-security

My requirement is to validate Class fields on the basis of external configuration file i.e xml. I dont want to use annotation as if I want to change some configuration, I will need to change class file which is not desirable. I assume this is implemented using Spring AOP, so there must be some namespace for external configuration in spring context xml file. Any help will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out the [XML configuration section](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/validator/4.1/reference/en-US/html/validator-xmlconfiguration.html) of the Hibernate Validator reference manual.  It might work for your requirements.

Comment: ericacm, thanks for the response. Yes, it looks like it will work for me. Though, I was hoping that same approach is there for Spring validation framework also. If it is there, please let me know. For the time being, I will go for Hibernater validation framework. Thanks a lot for your valuable comment.

Comment: You can use Hibernate Validator for Spring Validation.   See http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/validation.html#validation-beanvalidation

Comment: Thanks a lot ericacm, it really helps a lot.